# Vue reusable dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have no idea how to make reusable modal in vue. So, my idea is - I have global plugin which add global method  `$modal`  to Vue, I have base template  `ModalBase.vue`  with  `header, footer`  parts.

`ModalBase.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot name="modal-header"/>
        <slot name="modal-footer"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

From next code

```
import MyModal from 'MyModal.vue'
mounted () {
    this.$modal.open(MyModal, someData, modalOptions)
}
```

I need to get new combined modal window from merging `ModalBase.vue` and `MyModal.vue`. `MyModal.vue` template need to be placed between ModalBase header and footer. If MyModal already has a footer or header part, it will overwrite same ModalBase parts. All logic and `someData` mutations must be placed in `MyModal.vue`. So in my case ModalBase like boilerplate for modal window.

Maybe there is more simple solution to achieve this.

Comment: I don't really know what your question is. Could you edit your answer and include larger code segments and clearly state what you don't understand.

Comment: Tried to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use components. Check the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) and it may help. Basically you can put a component in a component as I think you want and then use the parent component in a page somewhere. It might start getting a bit messy if you want to replace part of a component if a child component is present and I honestly wouldn't know how to do that, perhaps someone else would.

Layering components like this can make it more difficult if you are trying to pass data between them so you need to be careful of that.

Also, your template code above would likely not work because as the error would tell you "Component template should contain exactly one root element." So you'd need:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot name="modal-header"/>
    <slot name="modal-footer"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Edited, thank you. Before I have implement modal with dynamic component `<component :is="component" v-bind="someData"/>` in `ModalBase` with providing some base methods to it. It's solves all problems except replacing footer with custom one.

Comment: Maybe there is any way to cut footer slot from MyModal and replace in ModalBase programmatically, before mount and render.

Comment: Actually you should be able to do what you want with slots. Slots can have a `v-if` condition and so you could maybe have a method with `getElementById` to see if there is a header or footer and set a boolean that is used by your `v-if`. I'll try and have a play around and see if I can post some code for this.